# dataframeから辞書型への変換について

Tags: python, pandas

dataframeのデータを辞書型に格納したいのですが、良い方法を教えてください。
画像のようなdataframeから下記のような辞書データを作りたいです。
movie_dict = {
            'UserId(1)':{
                        'MovieId(68646)': 10, 
                        'MovieId(113277)': 10},
            'UserId(2)':{...

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

とりあえず1ライナーで書いてみました。

```
{'UserId({})'.format(data[0]):{'MovieId({})'.format(record['MovieId']):record['Rating'] for record in data[1].to_dict('records')} for data in df.groupby('UserId')}
```

方針としては`groupby`でユーザごとのデータフレームにわけて、そのデータフレームのレコードごとに処理します。ループを明示的に書くと

```
movie_dict = {}
for data in df.groupby('UserId'):
    user_key = 'UserId({})'.format(data[0])
    movie_dict[user_key] = {}
    for record in data[1].to_dict('records'):
        movie_dict[user_key]['MovieId({})'.format(record['MovieId'])] = record['Rating']
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。このままですと、Keyerror:1が出てしまいます。for文を分解して、movie_dict['UserId({})'.format(data[0])] = {}
movie_dict['UserId(1)']['MovieId({})'.format(record['MovieId'])] = record['Rating']で、ほしい形が得られたのですが、for文をうまく回せないので、アドバイス頂ければと思います。

Comment: 1ライナーなコピペミス、forの方はkeyを文字列にしていたのを失念していましたので修正しました。お手数かけました

Comment: ありがとうございます、解決できました！

Answer (score 0):

既に解決済みですが、`UserId` と `MovieId` の組み合わせをキーにする方法もあるかと思います。具体的には、

```
dataframe.set_index(['UserId', 'MovieId'])
```

とします。

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
import pprint

df = pd.DataFrame(
  [
    [1, 68646, 10],
    [1, 113277, 10],
    [2, 454876, 8],
    [2, 790636, 7],
    [3, 1300854, 7],
  ],
  columns = ['UserId', 'MovieId', 'Rating'])

movie_dict = {}
for (u, m), r in df.set_index(['UserId', 'MovieId']).to_dict()['Rating'].items():
  movie_dict.setdefault('UserId('+str(u)+')', {}).update({'MovieId('+str(m)+')': r})

pprint.pprint(movie_dict)
## =>
## {'UserId(1)': {'MovieId(113277)': 10, 'MovieId(68646)': 10},
##  'UserId(2)': {'MovieId(454876)': 8, 'MovieId(790636)': 7},
##  'UserId(3)': {'MovieId(1300854)': 7}})
```